# Workspace add on for sheets not accessible unless release preferences set to 'Rapid Release' on G-Suite domain

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-marketplace

I released a Google workspace add-on for Sheets a week ago.

Installing and accessing via the workspace side panel menu works fine on personal gmail accounts.

However, on G-Suite accounts, it is not accessible/viewable in the side panel menu in sheets, unless the G-Suite admin sets release preferences to 'Rapid Release' in the domain settings: https://admin.google.com/u/0/ac/accountsettings/preferences?

This causes a big issue with distribution to any accounts that are not personal gmail accounts! Here's a short video of the issue: https://youtu.be/lSIrF9OtrZA

Has anyone else seen this? Is there a fix so we don't have to ask everyone who installs to activate this setting?

Comment: The release preferences pertain to features in products released by Google, not workspace developer add-ons. What makes you think this solves the issue?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I tested doing this and it works - as soon as I switch to Rapid Release, it is suddenly available. Wondering if it is a wider issue that workspace add-ons for Sheets (more generally, not just mine) are inactive unless this setting has been activated

Comment: Instead of using the Rapid Release setting, does the add-on have to be enabled in the add-on manager? `Add-ons > Manage add-ons > ⋮ > Use in this document` from the Sheets UI?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo thx for your reply. Unfortunately, that option does not appear to be available for workspace add-ons on sheets (but does for all others). I just see "Uninstall" for the add-on in question. Made a [Loom video of what I see here](https://www.loom.com/share/8889e4f722914c1aa1e39659fc19e81c).

Comment: @RafaGuillermo a good way to test this is installing the new [Box workspace add-on](https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/box_for_google_workspace_addon/828801433755). It does not appear for me in the sheets sidebar unless I activate rapid release setting.